# Escape characters, literal quotations, and variables in KornShell (ksh) script command

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

Brand new to KornShell (ksh). I have an absolutely painful and hopefully simple problem.

I need to run a script with a string argument that includes single quotations mark and a variable. In the shell, it looks like this:

```
run_script -x '*082512*'
```

And that works fine.

But once I try to run it in a script with a variable for the date, I can not produce those single quotes. I have made the "today's date" variable without problem:

```
today=$(date "+%m%d%y")
```

But the problem occurs when I try to run the script. I have tried every possible combination of quotes within quotes and escaping the single quotes etc. etc. to no avail.

Any insight regarding this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: In what way does `run_script -x "*${today}*"` fail to work? Note that the single quotes in your example are only meaningful to the shell, not your script: when your script grabs the argument, the single quotes are not present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

commenting here because the formatting is better.

Did you try

```
today=$(date "+%m%d%y")
run_script -x '*'"$today"'*'
```

As Glenn Jackman points out, quote are only 'seen' at the first level of shell invocation, where you typed in your command.

If the above doesn't help you, consider editing your question to show exact use case, with exact error messages or other non--expected behavior.

Good luck.

Comment: This worked.  Definitely thought I had tried that, but I guess not.  Thanks very much.